# How can I integrate SSLCommerze to my django app?

Tags: django, session, integration, payment

I have created a ecommerce site. Now i want to integrate payment method. By adding SSLCommerce to my site, all payment method will be taken care of in Bangladesh. But I don't know how can I add it to my Django app. Please help!

They said something session. But I did not get it. Here is thier github repo https://github.com/sslcommerz/SSLCommerz-Python?fbclid=IwAR0KkEH3H-AOwaWneQy0POGkTw6O3vvL9NiRM4amflyQEt54_W1g1rgYB48

Comment: How about pip install sslcommerz-lib

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrapper library called "sslcommerz-lib". To use it, you'll first need [an account on their sandbox environment](https://developer.sslcommerz.com/registration/). After completing the registration, collect your user credentials from email.

1. First install the package with `pip install sslcommerz-lib`
2. Import the library on your module `from sslcommerz_lib import SSLCOMMERZ`
3. Instantiate an object of the `SSLCOMMERZ` class with sandbox user credentials

```py
sslcz = SSLCOMMERZ({ 'store_id': <your_store_id>, 'store_pass': <your_password>, 'issandbox': True })
```

4. Build a dictionary with some info about the transaction and customer. In a real application, most of these data will be collected from user input.

```py
data = {
    'total_amount': "100.26",
    'currency': "BDT",
    'tran_id': "tran_12345",
    'success_url': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment-successful", # if transaction is succesful, user will be redirected here
    'fail_url': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment-failed", # if transaction is failed, user will be redirected here
    'cancel_url': "http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment-cancelled", # after user cancels the transaction, will be redirected here
    'emi_option': "0",
    'cus_name': "test",
    'cus_email': "test@test.com",
    'cus_phone': "01700000000",
    'cus_add1': "customer address",
    'cus_city': "Dhaka",
    'cus_country': "Bangladesh",
    'shipping_method': "NO",
    'multi_card_name': "",
    'num_of_item': 1,
    'product_name': "Test",
    'product_category': "Test Category",
    'product_profile': "general",
}
```

5. Get the api reponse

```py
response = sslcz.createSession(data)
```

6. After doing chores like updating db etc, redirect the user to 'GatewayPageURL' from the response we got earlier -

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect(response['GatewayPageURL'])
```

Comment: here you done the Creating a transaction Session with SSLCommerz Session API, after this how we can Create a IPN (Instant Payment Notification) Listener to receive the successful payment notification and then SSLCommerz will redirect the customer to your callback url

Answer (score 0):

SSLCOMMERZ - Python (sslcommerz-lib)
Note: If you're using this wrapper with our sandbox environment issandbox is true and live issandbox is false. (Details: Test Or Sandbox Account).

```
settings = { 'store_id': 'testbox', 'store_pass': 'qwerty', 'issandbox': True } 
sslcommerz = SSLCOMMERZ(settings)
```

Installation

```
pip install sslcommerz-lib
```

Authentication Keys
You can find your store_id and store_pass at the API Documentation Page. Create an account on SSLCOMMERZ, log in and visit this link: https://developer.sslcommerz.com/registration/

Usage
Create a Initial Payment Request Session

```
from sslcommerz_lib import SSLCOMMERZ 
settings = { 'store_id': 'testbox', 'store_pass': 'qwerty', 'issandbox': True }
sslcz = SSLCOMMERZ(settings)
post_body = {}
post_body['total_amount'] = 100.26
post_body['currency'] = "BDT"
post_body['tran_id'] = "12345"
post_body['success_url'] = "your success url"
post_body['fail_url'] = "your fail url"
post_body['cancel_url'] = "your cancel url"
post_body['emi_option'] = 0
post_body['cus_name'] = "test"
post_body['cus_email'] = "test@test.com"
post_body['cus_phone'] = "01700000000"
post_body['cus_add1'] = "customer address"
post_body['cus_city'] = "Dhaka"
post_body['cus_country'] = "Bangladesh"
post_body['shipping_method'] = "NO"
post_body['multi_card_name'] = ""
post_body['num_of_item'] = 1
post_body['product_name'] = "Test"
post_body['product_category'] = "Test Category"
post_body['product_profile'] = "general"


response = sslcz.createSession(post_body) # API response
print(response)
# Need to redirect user to response['GatewayPageURL']
```

Vaidate payment with IPN
from sslcommerz_lib import SSLCOMMERZ

```
settings = { 'store_id': 'test_testemi', 'store_pass': 'test_testemi@ssl', 'issandbox': True } 

sslcz = SSLCOMMERZ(settings)
post_body = {}
post_body['tran_id'] = '5E121A0D01F92'
post_body['val_id'] = '200105225826116qFnATY9sHIwo'
post_body['amount'] = "10.00"
post_body['card_type'] = "VISA-Dutch Bangla"
post_body['store_amount'] = "9.75"
post_body['card_no'] = "418117XXXXXX6675"
post_body['bank_tran_id'] = "200105225825DBgSoRGLvczhFjj"
post_body['status'] = "VALID"
post_body['tran_date'] = "2020-01-05 22:58:21"
post_body['currency'] = "BDT"
post_body['card_issuer'] = "TRUST BANK, LTD."
post_body['card_brand'] = "VISA"
post_body['card_issuer_country'] = "Bangladesh"
post_body['card_issuer_country_code'] = "BD"
post_body['store_id'] = "test_testemi"
post_body['verify_sign'] = "d42fab70ae0bcbda5280e7baffef60b0"
post_body['verify_key'] = "amount,bank_tran_id,base_fair,card_brand,card_issuer,card_issuer_country,card_issuer_country_code,card_no,card_type,currency,currency_amount,currency_rate,currency_type,risk_level,risk_title,status,store_amount,store_id,tran_date,tran_id,val_id,value_a,value_b,value_c,value_d"
post_body['verify_sign_sha2'] = "02c0417ff467c109006382d56eedccecd68382e47245266e7b47abbb3d43976e"
post_body['currency_type'] = "BDT"
post_body['currency_amount'] = "10.00"
post_body['currency_rate'] = "1.0000"
post_body['base_fair'] = "0.00"
post_body['value_a'] = ""
post_body['value_b'] = ""
post_body['value_c'] = ""
post_body['value_d'] = ""
post_body['risk_level'] = "0"
post_body['risk_title'] = "Safe"
if sslcz.hash_validate_ipn(post_body):
    response = sslcz.validationTransactionOrder(post_body['val_id'])
    print(response)
else:
    print("Hash validation failed")
```

Get the status or details of a Payment Request by sessionkey

```
from sslcommerz_lib import SSLCOMMERZ 
settings = { 'store_id': 'testbox', 'store_pass': 'qwerty', 'issandbox': True }
sslcz = SSLCOMMERZ(settings)

sessionkey = 'A8EF93B75B8107E4F36049E80B4F9149'
response = sslcz.transaction_query_session(sessionkey)
print(response)
```

Get the status or details of a Payment Request by tranid

```
from sslcommerz_lib import SSLCOMMERZ 
settings = { 'store_id': 'testbox', 'store_pass': 'qwerty', 'issandbox': True }
sslcz = SSLCOMMERZ(settings)

tranid = '59C2A4F6432F8'
response = sslcz.transaction_query_tranid(tranid)
print(response)
```